# Sort a some words in a string

Tags: java, string, sorting, key-value, treemap

Assuming there is a file:

```
Virginia Tyler Taylor Wilson
Ohio Grant Hayes Garfield Harrison_B McKinley Taft Harding
Massachusetts Kennedy Bush_GHW
New_York VanBuren Fillmore Roosevelt_T Roosevelt_F
```

I need to sort it in order, and below is my code:

```
TreeMap<String, String> map = new TreeMap<String, String>();
while (infile1.ready()){
String line = infile1.readLine();
String s = line.substring(0, line.indexOf(" "));
String p = line.substring(line.indexOf(" "));

map.put(s, p);
}

for (String p : map.keySet()){
System.out.println(p + " " + map.get(p));
}
```

My output is:

```
Massachusetts  Kennedy Bush_GHW
New_York  VanBuren Fillmore Roosevelt_T Roosevelt_F
Ohio  Grant Hayes Garfield Harrison_B McKinley Taft Harding
Virginia  Tyler Taylor Wilson
```

The expected output is:

```
Massachusetts **Bush_GHW Kennedy**
New_York **Fillmore Roosevelt_F Roosevelt_T VanBuren**
Ohio **Garfield Grant Harding Harrison_B Hayes McKinley Taft**
Virginia **Taylor Tyler Wilson**
```

The only difference is the order in the value, where I bold it in the expected output.
Is there a fast way to sort String p and puts it into the map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write in short way

```
Arrays.sort(line.substring(line.indexOf(" ")).split(" "));
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
String[] ps = line.substring(line.indexOf(" ")).split(" ");
Arrays.sort(ps);
```

then try combine ps to p with " ";

Answer (score 0):

```
Massachusetts **Bush_GHW Kennedy**
New_York **Fillmore Roosevelt_F Roosevelt_T VanBuren**
Ohio **Garfield Grant Harding Harrison_B Hayes McKinley Taft**
Virginia **Taylor Tyler Wilson**

In your above expected output how Bush Comes after mass..
So please explore output correctly.
```